# How to create new column with value from other table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table called 'menus':

```
 menu_id | sort | page_id | parent_page_id
---------|------|---------|----------------
 1       | 0    | 1       | NULL
 1       | 1    | 2       | 1
 1       | 2    | 3       | 1
 1       | 3    | 4       | 1
```

And a table called 'pages':

```
 id | url
----|-----------
 1  | vehicles
 2  | car
 3  | bicycle
 4  | bus
```

*I chose to store the data into separate tables because one page can be included in multiple menus.*

Now I want to do a query from which the result is:

```
 menu_id | page_id | sort | url      | parent_url
---------|---------|------|----------|------------
 1       | 1       | 0    | vehicles | NULL
 1       | 2       | 1    | car      | vehicles
 1       | 3       | 2    | bicycle  | vehicles
 1       | 4       | 3    | bus      | vehicles
```

The columns `menu_id`, `page_id`, `sort` and `url` can easily be retrieved using a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT
    menus.menu_id,
    pages.id AS page_id,
    menus.sort,
    pages.url
FROM menus
LEFT JOIN pages
ON menus.page_id = pages.id
ORDER BY sort
```

But how do I get the column `parent_url` in the query result?

Comment: `SELECT ... menus.url AS parent_url ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to JOIN to the `pages` table a second time to get the `parentURL`.  The first time that you join to `pages` use the `page_id`, then the second join will use the `parent_page_id`:

```
SELECT
    m.menu_id,
    p1.id AS page_id,
    m.sort,
    p1.url,
    p2.url parentUrl
FROM menus m
LEFT JOIN pages p1
  ON m.page_id = p1.id
LEFT JOIN pages p2
  ON m.parent_page_id = p2.id
ORDER BY m.sort;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fab8/4).  This gives a result:

```
| MENU_ID | PAGE_ID | SORT |      URL | PARENTURL |
|---------|---------|------|----------|-----------|
|       1 |       1 |    0 | vehicles |    (null) |
|       1 |       2 |    1 |      car |  vehicles |
|       1 |       3 |    2 |  bicycle |  vehicles |
|       1 |       4 |    3 |      bus |  vehicles |
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still struggling with joints, this is another lesson for me :)

Comment: Lesson #2: Doctors can help you with JOINTS. You come here for help with JOINs.

Comment: Haha of course, I'll stick with joins for now ;)
@bluefeet Could you elaborate the syntax, please? Why is `p2.url` not followed by `AS`, like `p1.id`? And, are `m`, `p1` and `p2` MySQL variables of some sort?

Comment: @Stan The `AS` is not required when giving an alias.  The `m`, `p1` and `p2` are table aliases which allows you to reference the table using that instead of the full table name.

Comment: Ah, I see. And the compiler doesn't know which tables are being referred without the unique aliases...I think I understand it.